# Bound Mismatch with generic arraylist that stores generic objects that implement comparable

Tags: java, generics

My teacher was saying that the bound mismatch error should disappear once I implement comparable in my Entry class.

This generates the error:

```
public class BucketList<V> implements BucketListADT<V> {

    //The Error underline under 'Entry' should clear once you make the
    //Entry object properly comparable. See Entry.java
    private ArrayList<MySortedArray<Entry<V>>> list;
    private int min;
    private int max;
```

Here is my Entry class that needs to implement Comparable:

```
public class Entry <V extends Comparable<V>> {
    private int key;
    private V val;
    
    public Entry(int k, V v) {
        key = k;
        val = v;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.val;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getValue()+"="+this.getKey();
    }
    
    public int compareTo(int key2){
        if(key > key2) return 1; 
    if(key < key2) return -1; 
    else           return 0;
    }
}
```

Should it be something besides `<V extends Comparable<V>>` in the `Entry` class declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really be useful to know a bit more about the error you are getting. What I can tell you so far is that your Entry class does no implement Comparable. What you are saying with that code is that V implements Comparable. Maybe you want that, maybe not. To let the rest of the code know that Entry implements Comparable you should write:

`public class Entry <V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<Entry<V>> { ...`

That is if you intend for V to also be Comparable. In that case you should also specify it like that in BucketList or else BucketList says it may have any V, even if it is not Comparable, but immediately after uses it as if it where guaranteed to be Comparable. If you don't intend for V to necessarily implement Comparable, just change `<V extends Comparable>` to `<V>`

Comment: Yeah, I want Entry to implement Comparable instead of extending it I realize now. I'm supposed to be comparing the key values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'Manuel Rene Pauls Toews' for the help.
Here is my Entry class that works properly now:

```
public class Entry <V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparable<Entry<V>> {
    private int key;
    private V val;
    
    public Entry(int k, V v) {
        key = k;
        val = v;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.val;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getValue()+"="+this.getKey();
    }
    

    public int compareTo(Entry entry){
        if(key > entry.key) return 1; 
    if(key < entry.key) return -1; 
    else           return 0;
    }

}
```